# Java query to solve stretch factor

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

this is the question :

> > write a Java Program that accepts a String and an integer stretch
> >     factor P as parameters and that replaces each element with k copies of
> >     that element. For example, if a variable called list stores the
> >     elements [hi, how, are, you?], then the call of stretch(list, 3); it
> >     will store [hi, hi, hi, how,how,how,are,are,are, you?, you?, you?]. If
> >     a stretch factor of 0 or less is passed, the list is made empty. In
> >     this case, print "EMPTY" You can assume that the input list will never
> >     be empty. Sample input: 3 hi how are you? sample output: hi hi hi how
> >     how how are are are you? you? You?

And this is my code :

```
class stretchF{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int b=sc.nextInt();
    String s=sc.nextLine();
    String[] splited=s.split("\\s");
  if(b<1){
      System.out.print("EMPTY");
  }else{
      for(int i=0;i<splited.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<b;j++){
            System.out.print(splited[i]+" ");
        }
    }
  }

}
```

}

Now I have edited the code

but still it is not passing the output test cases !

But it is not giving the right output!

Please tell what changes should I make to make this work ?

Comment: first `i<=b` should be `i<splited.length`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to change your codes:

```
 for(int i=0;i<=b;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<b;j++){
                System.out.print(splited[i]+" ");
            }
        }
```

into:

```
 for(int i=0;i<splited.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<b;j++){
                System.out.print(splited[i]+" ");
            }
        }
```

You wanted the outer for-loop to go through each element, but you didn't give the right range. (splited.length)

Also you need check the `b` value, for the `print "EMPTY"` case.

---

replace the scanner codes with below.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("String is:");
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Number is:");
    int b = sc.nextInt();
```

Comment: still not passing the test case @Kent

Comment: @rockybalboa123 "it doesn't work" is not a good statement to explain problem. I tested just now with the codes in a dummy class. it worked here.

Comment: Looks like u forgot `split()` to see ! that was creating problem